# Unable to connect ArcGIS Server - Error: Proxy server got bad address from remote server

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, error, proxy, connection

This is my problem. anybody know how to solve this?[image]

> We were unable to connect to ...
>
> Error: Proxy server got bad address from remote server (verify ther server is running).

Comment: Is your server running?

Comment: sorry. how to know whether server running or not?

Comment: You can take a look at this 
http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/configuring-a-one-machine-deployment.htm

Comment: That error is telling you that you have the wrong URL.  What happens if you attempt to go to the `domain/arcgis/manager` in your browser?   Did you configure a webadaptor or reverse proxy?  If not is the machine attempting to make the connection on the same network as the ArcGIS server?

Comment: Are you sure your URL is correct? ".domain.com" is not related to any ArcGIS serivce, it is a provider for webhosting, domainnames and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be that your trying to access an older version that isn't compatible, administrative connections can only be made with ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Desktop products that are on the same version.

ESRI has a a technical article on an error message that may be relevant to your issue [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40799)

Answer (score 1):

Just had this happen to us and my colleague figured out that there was an update on the server and a rule normally allowing traffic through port 443 was changed during the update.  Changing the firewall rule back fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check ArcGIS Server Manager to verify the machine (ArcGIS Server) that you can connect to. If you remote desktop connect to different machines, they may show in ArcCatalog, but you will receive that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we usually have is that the License Manager in ArcGIS Administrator is not correct. If License Manager is not correct, then ArcMap won't allow you to connect to a GIS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ***LAN settings*** in ***Internet Options*** have been changed! Check this.